# How can I filter out specific lines while still writing to the same file?

Tags: bash, sed, grep, cat, hosts

I set myself a *small* project that involved [StevenBlack's host file](https://github.com/StevenBlack/hosts). I know that he provides a way to make your own hosts file with his Python script, however I wanted to set myself a challenge.

The problem is as follows:

I have a script that gets the `Fakenews+Gambling+Social` hosts file.

However, I still want to access Reddit. And to make it worse, the file gets constantly updated. Meaning that I can't remove the lines with `sed -e '123,456d'`.

I think I got pretty close. But I'm not sure, here is the command

```
cat ./hosts | grep "# Reddit" -A10 | sed -e '1,11d'
```

While it does indeed remove the *Reddit* entries, I have no idea how to put it back together. Meaning, that with the command above I can indeed filter out the *Reddit* lines, but I don't know how to put back into the hosts file and not create an empty file.

It's my first post and I'm very bad at explaining problems. If there is any need for clarification, just say it. Also English isn't my first language, so that doesn't help.

EDIT: Example

`cd /home/myname/Documents/git`

`wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/StevenBlack/hosts/master/alternates/fakenews-gambling-social/hosts`

At this point, I have the raw hosts file. Now I want to filter out Reddit. The entries I want to remove are:

Reddit

0.0.0.0 reddit.com

0.0.0.0 www.reddit.com

0.0.0.0 i.reddit.com

0.0.0.0 redd.it

And now comes the problem. I don't know how to remove them from the hosts file, since the lines are changing constantly.

My approach was `cat ./hosts | grep "# Reddit" -A10 | sed -e '1,11d'`, which is in hindsight pretty useless.

Comment: Provide a short a sample input and corresponding expected output. Since you are not modifying the hosts file it is not clear why you want to put it back.

Comment: Provided example. And I *do* want to modify the hosts file. I want to remove the Reddit entries while keeping the rest of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter them as you download:

```
wget "$url" -O- | grep -v 'redd.\?it' > hosts
```